# Plotting columns of "yes" and "no" data in R

Tags: r

I am trying to learn R from a textbook and the data I am using is called College.csv, and it is found [here](https://www.statlearning.com/resources-second-edition).

The question from the textbook is

> use the plot function to produce side-by-side boxplots of Outside versus Private.

I have tried

```
plot(college[,1], college[,9])
```

but I get a blank window along with some messages:

> 1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
> 2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
> 3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Try `boxplot` instead of `plot`

Comment: Try `boxplot(Outstate ~ Private, college)`.